# Knockout binding on focusout for a div containing a form

Tags: knockout.js

I'm trying to achieve a kind of what is done in the simple example 1 in ko documentation [for the has focus binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/hasfocus-binding.html) but applied to a div containing a form, and just in one direction would be fine

Using focusout in the code below I face the problem that once focusOnDiv is set to true, if I change from one input to another the event is triggered and the is coming back to false. I was expecting not to be triggered as it's inside the div. I can use focusin in the same event binding to set it to true as in the fiddle but I doubt whether this solution is acceptable

Html:

```
<div tabindex ="-1" class="parentdiv" data-bind="event: { focusout: resetFocusOnDiv}">
     <p><div>Just a div</div></p>
     <p><span>And a span</span></p>
     <p><select>
         <option>First</option>
         <option>Second</option>
         </select>
     </p>
     <input type="checkbox">Checkbox</input>
    <p><input data-bind="value: firstValue" /></p>
    <p><input data-bind="value: secondValue" /></p>
</div>
<div data-bind="text: focusOnDiv"></div>
<input type="button" data-bind="click: setFocusOnDiv" value="Click">
```

Js:

```
var viewModel = function() {
    var self= this;

    self.firstValue = ko.observable('a');
    self.secondValue = ko.observable('b');

    self.focusOnDiv = ko.observable(false);

    self.setFocusOnDiv = function(){
        self.focusOnDiv(true);
    };

    self.resetFocusOnDiv = function(){
        self.focusOnDiv(false);
    };
};


ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Qyn9b/)

Comment: What's the desired result?

Comment: The result is the one I'm getting in the fiddle with the two events bindings, although I don't know if it's slick enough. But I don't understand why just with the code I posted (i.e. not using focusin binding it doesn't work, as the bool is set to false after clicking in one input and then going to the other one)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly, you wanted to give an element focus upon click of a button in knockout. You can accomplish such a task by using the focus function:

```
<input type="button" data-bind="click: focusDiv" value="Click">

self.focusDiv = function(){
     $('#focusId').focus();
};
```

Comment: Thanks @ArrowKneeous tbh I had to review my question as I forgot what I was asking!. Not clear but I understood it (my mind's still messy I guess). I was trying to understand why I do need the focusin event binding in the parentdiv more that how to bind the click as you point to me. Thanks

Comment: If you are trying to mimic the example 1 in the knockout hasfocus documentation (without using hasfocus) you must have the following: 
1)an event on the texbox that sets your focusOnDiv variable to true when the textbox has been given focus. (focusin)
2)an event on the textbox that sets your focusOnDiv variable to false when it loses focus. (focusout)
3)a button that gives focus to the element. ($('#elementSelector').focus());